# Convert a Dictionary<string,List<string>> into a List<string,string>

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, .net-core

I am using dictionary 
`Dictionary<string,List<string>>` which will have values like

```
Key        ||        Values
1                     a,b,c
2                     d,e
```

I want to convert this dictionary into a list of Objects of type MyClass

MyClass has two properties i.e.

```
Class MyClass{
 public string ID { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Which would be

```
1 ,  a
1 ,  b
1 ,  c
2 ,  d
2 ,  e
```

I have tried some things like using Keys.Tolist and Values.ToList but have not been successful in getting what i need.

I am aware that this can be done using a loop, but i prefer not using it since the data that i will be dealing with will be in hundreds of thousands i.e.  hundreds of thousands of keys and tens of millions of values.

Can someone help me in finding an efficient way to deal with this?

Comment: You can just do `dictionary.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value.Select(name => new MyClass { ID = kvp.Key, Name =name })).ToList()`, but that still does looping under the covers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that in one line and flatten a dictionary values using [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___System_Func___0___1___2__) method, but it's still using a loop under the hood

```cs
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{
    { "1", new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" } },
    { "2", new List<string> { "d", "e" } }
};

var result = dict
    .SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value, (kvp, s) => new MyClass { ID = kvp.Key, Name = s })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by flattening your list with strings with select statement from LINQ. First, you iterate over dictionary collection, and then inside you iterate over a list of strings and create new objects from it. Below I placed an example that should help you understand it.

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    var list = new List<string>
    {
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
    };

    var list2 = new List<string>
    {
        "d",
        "e"
    };

    var dict = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();
    dict.Add("1", list);
    dict.Add("2", list2);

    var x = dict.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Select(z => new MyClass
    {
        Id = x.Key,
        Name = z
    })).ToList();
```